# Iterate Over SharedMailbox

Tags: python

I am trying to read into a sharedmailbox named SharedMailbox, TEST-Investigation and has a subfolder named BoA ICL Ack Notifications. I am getting the results but at the same time its also populating messaged from my REGULAR inbox. So i am getting duplicate emails returned because I have some emails the same on my inbox and also on the sharedmailbox so its returning emails from both boxes.

```
def readEmail():

    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    folder = outlook.Folders.Item('SharedMailbox, TEST-Investigation')
    inbox = folder.Folders.Item('Inbox')
    subfolder = inbox.Folders.Item('BoA ICL Ack Notifications')
    messages = subfolder.Items

    

    ggglastHourMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastHourDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p') + "'")

    ggg_emails_l = []

    for ggg_email in ggglastHourMessages:
        if 'P2 Cust ID 1111111 File' in ggg_email.Subject:
            print(ggg_email)
```

Comment: You've told us what's happening, but you haven't asked an actual question.  What is your question?

Comment: How can i only get my sharedmailbox emails? I dont want my regular inbox emails.